# Formatting column font color by another column's value

Tags: json, sharepoint, formatting

I have a SharePoint List that include columns Title, valColor, & Pinstyle.  I want to the color the Title column by the hex code color value in valColor. I thought the below would work, but it doesn't. Any ideas?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": [$valColor]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "" for [$valColor]:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "[$valColor]"
  }
}
```

[image]